# iOS7 Safari: tapping on fixed positioned header bar with higher z-index triggers event handler of the element underneathe it

Tags: ios, scroll, mobile-safari

My web page has a fixed positioned header bar. As you scroll, the content will go under the header bar, using z-index. Clicking on the blocks in the content area will toggle its color. Click anywhere in header should not trigger the event handler of the block.

But this does not work on iOS7 Safari. Tapping on header made blocks change color. As I searched the internet, it seems to be iOS7 bug. Tried window.scrollTo(0,0), and extra 20px thing, did not help.

Interestingly I noticed the same problem on Yahoo Finance and Yahoo Sport web app on iOS7 mobile Safari, where they have fixed header too.

Anyone know a good fix?

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" >
<style>
header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    background: grey;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
}

.content {
    z-index: 1;
    margin-top: 60px;
}
.block {
    background: red;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 4%;
}
.block.green {
    background: green;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        Fixed positiond header.
    </header>

    <div class="content">
        <p>On iOS Safari, scroll the blocks below the header, tap the header on the top edge to let the address bar appear. Then tap anywhere in the header, you will see block toggling colors.
        </p>

        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>

    </div>


<!-- Include jQuery -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".block").on("click", function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("green");
    });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This does appear to be a bug, or at least a quirk in the way Safari on iPad is handling this. For a workaround, it seems that if you add and onclick event handler to your header it resolves the issue:

```
<header onclick="">
```

You can also add one with jQuery if you prefer that method.